# Scaling SignalR on Amazon AWS

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, amazon-web-services, signalr, signalr-hub

I wanted to know how to Scale SignalR on Amazon AWs. From my understanding, in order to scale SignalR I need to deploy my website on several EC2 servers. The problem is that there isn't a connection between the two or more servers. There is an option to use Redis DB to make the servers talk to each other.

My questions are:

1. Do I need also to scale Redis DB?
2. Does the messages data are saved to the DB permanently or they deleted when the messages 
   are sent? (I don't want the DB to save the messages because it can become very big)
3. Any recommended configuration on Amazon to get started with a scalable SignalR deployment?

Comment: might be a better fit for server fault

Comment: But SignalR people are answering questions here..mmm.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was posted, Amazon has introduced [ElastiCache for Redis](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/09/04/amazon-elasticache-for-redis/).

Comment: [Amazon MemoryDB for Redis](https://aws.amazon.com/memorydb/) is also now an option as it is a Redis-compatible, durable, in-memory database service.

Answer (score 1):

1) You should find out if you need to scale Redis before worrying about how to scale Redis.

2) Redis is an in-memory dataset (http://redis.io/topics/introduction); so it doesn't have to persist to disk.

3) I'd recommend following the advice given in SignalR wiki (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) for setting up SignalR (the fact you're using AWS EC2 doesn't really matter) - then come back with any specific issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to know if the messages are saved or they are volatile and get removes after sent

Comment: It depends how you configure it - if configured as a cache it wouldn't be storing your data.

Comment: how can I configure it as a cache?

Comment: I haven't setup Redis before so can't really help out on this one.

Comment: Before you try to scale the SignalR solution, are you sure that you need to scale it like this? Have you got a number of clients you need to scale to 10k, 100k, 1m, 10m? Do you expect to be sending a few huge groups of clients the same message or will you have lots of groups that have small numbers of clients? Does it matter if a client looses a message while they're disconnected? These answers will affect how you choose to architect the state in between the signalr servers.